# Create virbr0 for virsh

Tags: debian, networking, kvm, qemu, virsh

I'm trying to setup a KVM based VMs on a local server, and following this doc: https://wiki.debian.org/KVM

In this documentation it states that you'll get `virbr0` for bridge connection, but unfortunately it wasn't created automatically. Doc suggest to use virt-manager to fix that, but I'm having just a standard debian server installation w/o GUI. So how can I create that from command line?

I have created br0, all looks good:

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:c6:9c:0f:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:c6:9c:0f:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.200/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21f:c6ff:fe9c:f0d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ sudo ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0


$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id           STP enabled interfaces
br0         8000.001fc69c0f0d   no          eth0
```

notice, there're no `virbr0`.

If I try to create ifage-bridge I get error:

```
$ virsh iface-bridge eth0 br0
error: failed to get interface 'eth0'
error: internal error: couldn't find interface named 'eth0': required entry missing
```

I also have bridge configured for qemu, which I did manually and added to qemu autostart:

```
$ cat /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/bridge.xml
<network>
  <name>bridge</name>
  <bridge name="br0"/>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
</network>
```

And I can't create/start a VM because of bridge:

```
$ virt-install --virt-type kvm --name testvm --network bridge
Starting install...
Retrieving file MANIFEST...                  | 3.3 kB     00:00 ...
Retrieving file linux...                     | 6.0 MB     00:08 ...
Retrieving file initrd.gz...                 |  29 MB     00:56 ...
Allocating 'testvm.qcow2'                    | 8.0 GB     00:00
ERROR    failed to retrieve file descriptor for interface: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

It works if I omit `--network` configuration. This VM wouldn't have network, so useless basically. If I add a bridge config by `virsh edit testvm`:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
</interface>
```

and run, it will fail anyway:

```
$ virsh start testvm
error: Failed to start domain testvm
error: failed to retrieve file descriptor for interface: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

What I did incorrectly? How I should add `virbr0` and hot to setup network for VMs?

I have a fresh Debian Jessie installation, nothing was installed except core components, ssh and kvm/qemu/libvirt

Answer (score 2):

The reason was insufficient rights to use bridge from non-root user.

[Documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/KVM#Installation) states that:

> libvirt defaults to qemu:///session for non-root. So from <youruser>
>   you'll need to do:
>
> `$ virsh --connect qemu:///system list --all`

It wasn't clear that you have to specify it for installation, and when you would do that. It turns out it's a *required* command line option for non-root user.

Correct command to install a new VM with networking should include following:

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system .......
```

Or it's also possible to install it directly from `root` user

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should work:

```
# cat /tmp/virt-net-example.xml
<network connections='9'>
  <name>some-virt-net</name>
  <uuid>530f11c4-617b-447c-bdba-704f34374277</uuid>
  <bridge name='virbr42' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='42:13:37:23:21:87'/>
  <ip address='172.20.42.254' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='172.20.42.1' end='172.20.42.42'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
# virsh net-define /tmp/virt-net-example.xml
# virsh net-start some-virt-net
Network some-virt-net started

# brctl show virbr42
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
virbr42         8000.421337232187       yes             virbr42-nic

# link show virbr42-nic
99: virbr42-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr42 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:13:37:23:21:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Tested just now on FC22 against libvirt 1.2.13

Comment: thanks. could you elaborate it a little more? what so you think should be modified in my config to make it working? because it doesn't look like adding mac address will help. so there should be something important in your example, but I don't understand what exactly

Comment: “what so you think should be modified in my config”  -- not the config, but let libvirt create the bridge. It will do that on its own. In your VM definition you then reference the bridge as ``<target dev='vnet42'/>`` in the interface section.

Answer (score 0):

You already have br0 configured, it's good enough. The proper virt-install option is `--network bridge=br0`

EDIT: and example of an interface attached to a bridge, as promised in comments:

```
</interface>
  <mac address='00:1a:4a:01:00:04'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <target dev='vnet2'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <link state='up'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
</interface>
```

`target dev` and `alias name` are optional afaik

Comment: Tried, same result, same error. So maybe it's not because of non-existing `virbr0`, but something else related to that bridge? because it works without specifying `--network` option. Something is wrong there, but `Transport endpoint is not connected` doesn't make it clear

Comment: I use this all the time on RHEL, you might be running into a Debian specific bug.

Comment: Do you know any way to debug it? `virsh` logs/output are non-informative, and `Transport endpoint is not connected` doesn't give any clue. `-d 0` doesn't provide additional log to that error message

Comment: try to simply create a VM with virt-manager and attach it to br0, see if that works. If it does, I'd simply stick to the manual creation way, or if you really need automation, use virt-builder instead of virt-install. It's way less buggy, especially and that's important on non-RH distros that don't really do any quality testing like Debian

Comment: not sure what you mean by _attach it to br0_. I've tried to create simple VM without networking, but if I edit its xml and add bridge network (there's example in the question) it failed to run. I don't know about other way to attach it to br0. I'll try virt-builder, thanks

Comment: This is probably a bug in your build of libvirt. I am adding an example of a working interface definition you can try yourself. The brctl output seems to be in good order